# Getting the next data piece out of an array for a loop

Tags: c#

I have temperature data stored in an array, but need to use that data for a while loop. What I have so far is:

```
      public int BelowValueCounter(string tempValueIn)
      {

        int.TryParse(tempValueIn, out tempValueOut);
        int checkValue = tempData[0];  
        while (tempValueOut > checkValue)
        {
            belowCounter++;
        }
        return belowCounter;

      }
```

I just don't know how to increment `tempData[0]` so that it moves on to `tempData[1]` to repeat until the while loop condition is satisfied. Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered a for loop?  With your current code you need to define a variable you can increment every loop. Be careful not to go past the end of the array.

Comment: for (int i, i < tempData.size(), i++)

Comment: How does `tempValueIn` look like?

Comment: @dram c# != java

Comment: @astidham2003 Thanks, took a look into a foreach loop and made it work!

Comment: @moparjoe95 then either post your solution and mark it as *acceped* or delete it.

Comment: @L.B: `for (int i, i < tempData.size(), i++)` isn't valid in Java either :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the while loop, you need a variable for counting - here `i` -  to get access to the desired array entry:

```
public int BelowValueCounter(string tempValueIn)
{
    int.TryParse(tempValueIn, out tempValueOut);
    int i = 0;
    int checkValue = tempData[i];  

    while (tempValueOut > checkValue)
    {
        belowCounter++;
        i++;
        checkValue = tempData[i];
    }

    return belowCounter;
  }
```

Or consider using a for loop:

```
public int BelowValueCounter(string tempValueIn)
{
    int.TryParse(tempValueIn, out tempValueOut);

    for (int i = 0; i < tempData.Length; i++)
    {
        if (tempValueOut > tempData[i])
        {
            belowCounter++;
            continue;
        }

        break;
    }

    return belowCounter;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a for loop, foreach loop, or a linq query.

```
void Main()
{
    var counter = BelowValueCounter_UsingFor(46);
    //var counter = BelowValueCounter_UsingLinq(46);
    Console.WriteLine(counter); 
}

decimal[] temperatures = new decimal[] { 40, 40, 45, 60, 70 };

public int BelowValueCounter_UsingLinq(decimal tempValueIn)
{
    return temperatures.Count(a => a < tempValueIn);    
}

public int BelowValueCounter_UsingFor(decimal tempValueIn)
{
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < temperatures.Length; i++)
    {
        if (temperatures[i] < tempValueIn)
            counter++;
    }

    return counter; 
}
```